# Power BI: Relative Time Under 5 Hours returns no data

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a PBI desktop dashboard I've created to pull machine data from a local SQL server. I'm using a relative date time filter on one of the pages to drill down data for live feed, however anything under 5 hours of the relative time, the data goes blank.

I use 4 log tables for the raw data, each having their own time stamp for each instance. Each are related using a ID table with other general information contained. In addition, time is related using a calculated table to create a timeframe of all instances:

[Relationship Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX5lk.png)

```
DateTable = distinct(union(SUMMARIZE(LogFault,LogFault[Time]),SUMMARIZE(LogGood,LogGood[Time]),SUMMARIZE(LogReject,LogReject[Time]),SUMMARIZE(LogState,LogState[Time])))
```

[5 Hours Relative Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6g95.png)

[4 hours relative time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6AVm.png)

As you can see from the top right of the images, not even the times are pulled to the page. Is there a limitation to PBI on the relative time function? This wouldn't make sense to me if there is a "minutes" option under relative time. Any feedback on this would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL is a _language_, and I can't find any SQL above. Perhaps you should add the <sql-server> tag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking in the future, unfortunately PowerBI desktop, along with service, appears to only like to work in the UTC time zone. So the relative date/time was filtering based on the UTC time zone, not my time zone (EST). In order to resolve this, I had to create a new calculated column next to my distinct time stamps to correct for the time zone. I then used the adjusted time for the relative time filtering, but the charts remained under the original time  stamps.

UTC to EST time zone adjust

```
UTC_AdjustTZ = FORMAT(DateTable[Time]+TIME(4,0,0),"General Date")
```

[Chart Example after adjust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duHav.png)

[Chart after fix implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9QdK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your filter on Date Table doesn't reach the destined table. Normally filter moves from one side to many side, then one side to many side in a chain of relationships; but
In your case for example:
Filter goes from Date Table to Log Reject then It can't move to RejectDefinitions because of the filter direction. You have 2 options here:

```
1) Change the model relationships : Make Log Reject(One side) and RejectDefinitions(Many side) if It is possible.
```

OR

```
2) Set the filter direction as Both in the model.
```

You need to do this for all the remaining log tables(LogFault-FaultDefinitions,Logstate-StateDefinitions)

I hope It solves your problem. Please check that your model is not ambiguous after making those changes.